# assign selected option value from database

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form which contains a dropdown list of countries generated from database. The values are stored in database. There is an option in which user can view or update the valuesinserted.  For updating all the form values get fetched from database. What i require is that when form is loaded for updating the selected option of the country dropdown must be that stored in the database. 
For eg: if from the following dropdown option2 is selected and inserted into database.

```
 Dropdown: |option1|<selected>
           |option2|
           |option3|
```

during update it should be like this

```
 Dropdown: |option1|
           |option2|<selected>
           |option3|
```

Here is the code i tried.

```
      $selected = $list["country_country_name"];

     <tr><td>Country</td><td><select onchange="getCountry(this.value);" name="country" id="country" ><?php  foreach( $query as $qry ) { 
     print '<option value="'.$qry["country_country_name"].'"'; 
     if( $qry["country_country_name"] == $selected ) print'selected'; 
     print '>'.$qry["country_country_name"].'</option>'."\n";} ?>
     </select></td></tr>
```

Comment: the person who downvoted pls tell the reason so that i can make my question clear if thats the reason

Comment: why dont you use a select ? with an list of options ? with that you can fetch the selected option. do you want an example?

Comment: i am populating my dropdown from db. if this is not what u meant pls provide eg:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$selected = $list["country_country_name"];

```
 <tr><td>Country</td>
 <td>
 <select onchange="getCountry(this.value);" name="country" id="country" >
 <?php  foreach( $query as $qry ) { 
    $sel = '';
   if( $qry["country_country_name"] == $selected ) 
    $sel = 'selected="selected"';           

    echo '<option value="'.$qry["country_country_name"].'" '.$sel.'>'.$qry["country_country_name"].'</option>'."\n";
    } ?>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('country'); ?>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="list" name="list">
    <option value=""> Please Select </option>
    <?
        $list = array('1',
                        '2',
                        '3',
                        '4',
                        '5',
                        '6');

        while ($L = array_shift($list)) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?=$L?>" <? if($selected == $L){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> > 
                    <?= $L ?> 
                </option> 
            <?
         }
    ?>
</select>
```

you can simple get the selected option with this:

```
$("#list").val();
```

try please.

Answer (score 0):

When your option tag's `value` attribute contains the same value as the option's text, the value attribute is not necessary -- so omit it.

Below shows an inline condition statement.

```
<tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td><select onchange="getCountry(this.value);" name="country" id="country">
        <?php
        foreach ($query as $row) { 
            echo "<option" ,
                ($row["country_country_name"] == $list['country_country_name'] ? ' selected' : '') ,
                "{$row['country_country_name']}</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```