# dropdown value start from user selected item in edit mode

Tags: php, html, mysqli

In my app I want to edit user data.There has a dropdown and that option value comes from my data base.When I trying to edit user data that dropdown value start from start always but I want If user data already selected then in edit mode option value start from previous data.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="height">
        <option value="">Choose Your Height</option>
        <?php
             $basic_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM profilepersonalinfo WHERE userid = '$userid'");
             $brow = mysqli_fetch_array($basic_query);
             $height = $brow[4];
             $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT heightname FROM heightinfo");
             while ($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        if($height == $rowc[0])
                                            $selected = "selcted";
                                        else
                                            $selected = "";
                                        echo "<option value=" . $rowc[0] . " " . $selected . ">" . $rowc[0];
                                    }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

this is my dropdown code. Please help me.

Comment: you mean in the edit page previously selected option is selected?

Comment: yes....user height already inserted in other table. If user want to edit height then first option is the previous height.then other option comes.

Comment: Use the attribute selected at option to start from the height that is stored in DB. Just like: `echo "<option ".(($rowc[0]  == $DBValue) ? 'selected' : '')." value=" . $rowc[0] . ">" . $rowc[0];`

Comment: have you fetched previous height?Yes then which variable

Comment: yes.I already fetch height in this page but I didn't understand how to link with this query..this is only select box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign selected option value from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799445/assign-selected-option-value-from-database)

Comment: When the option's `value` attribute is the same as the option's text value, you can omit the `value` declaration entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your while loop code I consider $previosuHeight is your previously selected height

```
while ($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($previosuHeight == $rowc[0])
       $selected = "selected";
    else
       $selected = "";
    echo "<option value=" . $rowc[0] ." ".$selected.">" . $rowc[0]."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Your $previosuHeight is matched with $rowc[0]?

Comment: can you see in inspect element any option having selected attribute

Comment: now check i update my answer option closing tag is missing there

Comment: Missing option closing tag

Comment: I change that thing but nothing changed in ouput

Comment: You miss selected spelling  check by mistake you type selcted

Comment: I change that but still now nothing changed in output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182486/discussion-between-sachin-and-arpan-sarkar).